# android get current wallpaper and set it

Tags: android

i get the current wallpaper and convert it into bitmap and again convert it to string base64 and save it in sharedprefrences and get the wallpaper from shareprefrences and set it to as a wallpaper the all code is in loop which get set every 5 sec. every thing working there is only one issue wallapeper set correctly but when it set again again after some time wallpaper crash or destroy slowly slowly. please see my code why wallpaper crash slowly slowly.help me with some code thanks.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        Drawable wallpaper_profile3 = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap_profile3 = ((BitmapDrawable) wallpaper_profile3).getBitmap();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos_profile3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap_profile3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos_profile3);
            final byte[][] b_profile3 = {baos_profile3.toByteArray()};
            String encodedImage_profile3 = Base64.encodeToString(b_profile3[0], Base64.DEFAULT);

            wallpaper_sharedprefrences_profile3 = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_PROFILE3, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = wallpaper_sharedprefrences_profile3.edit();
            edit.putString(PROFILE2_WALLPAPER, encodedImage_profile3);
            edit.commit();

            load_wallpaper_profile3 = wallpaper_sharedprefrences_profile3.getString(PROFILE2_WALLPAPER, "");

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos2_profile3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final byte[][] b2_profile3 = {baos2_profile3.toByteArray()};
            b2_profile3[0] = Base64.decode(load_wallpaper_profile3 , Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bit_profile3 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b2_profile3[0], 0, b2_profile3[0].length);

                WallpaperManager wallpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

                        try {
                            wallpaper.setBitmap(bit_profile3);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//                        wallpaper.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }, 5000);
```

this is real image
[image]

and this is some time aftar image
[image]